# Change initial directory in windows powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using windows powershell for an application of my project. I'd like to change the initial directory, that I find when I open the program.

I'd like to have my project's directory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want powershell to launch by default with the working directory of your project. What you need to do is create a profile and set it up.

You can do that by simply doing something of the sort of

```
New-item –type file –force $Profile
notepad.exe $Profile
```

This will open the profile configuration file. Inside that file you can write something like

```
Set-Location C:\Path\To\Project
Clear-Host
```

Save and close the file then do

```
. $Profile
```

Answer (score 1):

create a profile in powershell. You can find step by step instructions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff461033.aspx).

Essentially `New-item –type file –force $profile`

Once you do that use `Set-Location`, you can specify a directory after it like `Set-Location C:\blah...\...\` Now, every time you open PowerShell, you will open on this location.